# Socorro - django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install Socorro on fresh Ubuntu 10.04 (Amazon EC2). I am following [this manual](http://socorro.readthedocs.org/en/latest/development/build-from-source.html) and I am on the step 6.2.8, and I am having a problem with following command:

**./manage.py syncdb --noinput**

This is the error:

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file**

What seems to be the problem?

And this is the hole log:

```
Syncing...
Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    manage.main()
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/funfactory/manage.py", line 144, in main
    execute_from_command_line(argv)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 92, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/management/__init__.py", line 37, in new_execute
    return original_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 160, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 132, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 127, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/etc/socorro/socorro-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 347, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: The database is usually configured in a file called settings.py. Can you find this file in your project? Is the database configured there?

Comment: I really don't know :D. I am trying to locate the file, but without the success for now...

Comment: Step 6.2.8: "cd webapp-django". So, webapp-django is a Django app. Each app should have settings.py inside. Take a look at this tutorial, in particular, at Database setup section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/